# Trouble connecting to virtualbox postgresql on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm having trouble connecting to postgres from my local copy of rails.  Postgresql is running on a virtualbox with user postgres, but when I try to run rake db:migrate, I get a

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "[my mac login username]"

Shouldn't it be trying to connect with the username specified in my database.yml?

Here's a link to that.

http://pastie.org/7329321

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you running your rake db:migrate from inside your virtual box? And can you log in to postgres from the command line in the virtual box using the credentials that you've put in the database.yml file?

Comment: running rake db:migrate locally, can connect with psql on the virtualbox, can connect with those credentials on pgadmin3 locally

Comment: Just not sure why it's using my mac login username to try to connect to the virtualbox

Comment: I can also connect with psql on my mac to the virtualbox postgres instance

Comment: your configuration is using `localhost` since it is a vm I think you need to specify the IP of the vm ?

Comment: specifying the port explicitly in the database.yml fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

try changing "user" to "username" in your database.yml.